# jQuery UI dialog - text not selected second time shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, prompt

I am trying to simulate the internal javascript function prompt with the jQuery UI dialogs.
Almost work perfectly - just one minor error :-)

When the dialog is shown a second time (without a page reload) the text in the input field is not selected - why.

I use this code:

```
function modalprompt(text, title, prompt, callback) {
    var newDiv = $("<div title='" + title + "'/>");

    function okreply() {
        newDiv.dialog("close");
        if (callback) callback($("#promptid").val());
    }

    function cancelreply() {
        newDiv.dialog("close");
        if (callback) callback(false);
    }
    newDiv.keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            okreply();
        }
    });
    /*
  newDiv.focus(function()
  {
    this.select();
  });
  */
    var htmltext = "<p>" + text + "</p>";
    htmltext += "<input id='promptid' type='text' name='promptid' value='" + prompt + "' style='width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;'>";
    newDiv.html(htmltext).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 480,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#promptid").select();
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $("#promptid").select();
        },
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $("#promptid").select();
        },
        buttons: [{
            text: $.alerts.okButton,
            click: function () {
                okreply();
            }
        }, {
            text: $.alerts.cancelButton,
            click: function () {
                cancelreply();
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

You can test it yourself here: http://pcrypt.dk/dev/login.php?logout

Just activate the link "ModalPrompt test" 2 times

Must be something relating to the fact that the second time shown the dialog is already created. All the $("#promptid").select(); calls do fire without any result so something must change this afterwards?

Thank you in advance!
Benny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I do not know why it dows not work, but adding this event handler:

```
close: function(event, ui) { newDiv.remove(); },
```

Does the trick. So somehow when there is more that one div created the selected call goes to the first div and does not affect the shown dialog.